# Making a Quiz Game in JavaScript, how do I create a database for keeping user's scores?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, database, server-side

I am creating a Quiz Game using HTML,CSS,JavaScript. I want to add leaderboards displaying user's name and score before deploying,but have no idea what technology to use and how to do it. I was thinking about using a JSON file to store the top10 scores that will be displayed on the leaderboards page. Can I do that? What is the best way to implement the scores? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using something like [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) would probably be the easiest option

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the aim of the project, there are a few ways of doing this. I've listed some of the easiest to use here.

### Players on the same computer

If your project is designed to be played on the same computer every time, [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) is a good way to go. You can store your JSON data in the browser for it to be accessed next time the game is used.

### Players on different computers

On the other hand. If you wish for your app to be played by people on different computers, Google's [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) service would be perfect. You can store data in the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database) or the [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore) service. You can also host your game as a website on there with [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/products/hosting). Google has a generous free tier that I'm sure will meet your needs.